# Would you consider this a stupid use of a class file?

Tags: php, oop

I have this class, and I was wondering, do you consider it a waste? As in should I do this? I understand how class's work and what makes them good but im failing (in a website point of view) to understand what use they have.

```
<? 
class PageHandler {
    var $html;
    function header () {
        $this->html .= "<html>
            <head>
                <title>Nuclear Summer</title>
            </head>
        <body>";
    }
    function footer () {
        $this->html .= "
            </body>
            </html>
            ";
    }
    function input ($html) {
        $this->html .= $html;
    }
    function output () {
        echo $this->html;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you're using Class's I assume you're working with some sort of MVC framework. In that case, you shouldn't be putting your HTML markup (the View) into your class (the Model).

Comment: Thank you people, looking up on some frameworks and MVC now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

This is a bad use of a class. What you're using a class for is what you should be using *views* for (if you're going for a [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) approach, which is a good way to go).

You create a main `layout` view, which contains code common to all pages (e.g. header, footer) and then you route incoming requests to an appropriate controller, which fills in the "middle" of the layout with appropriate content.

CodeIgniter is a great PHP framework for getting to grips with MVC. It even has [documentation on it](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html).

Comment: What's wrong with wrapping html inside a helper class ?!
MVC is about splitting database actions, website's logic and visual output, not about how to do it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your PageHandler is in terms of PHP frameworks something like a "view"-class. You can instantiate it for a page and provide it with more functionality. You are reusing the header and the footer, so that's generally speaking a godd idea.

But your example is to simple to say more about it.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of adding more things like a css and script function to include different things. But it all seems a bit pointless? What makes this better than say literally including a file called header.php and footer.php?

Comment: Nothing, depending on your use case. If you're using PHP purely to break your HTML files in reusable chunks, you're better of creating `header.php` type files, and then `include`'ing them.

Answer (score 1):

this is example for php4 and not usual for php5, also this is not the best usage for classes to create output templates, try to explore Zend Framework it is good enough example of OOP and MVC in PHP http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/

Example of your code for php5 but still not the best usage for OOP

```
class PageHandler {

    private $html;

    private function header () {
        $this->html .= "<html>
            <head>
                <title>Nuclear Summer</title>
            </head>
        <body>";
    }
    private function footer () {
        $this->html .= "
            </body>
            </html>
            ";
    }
    public function input ($html) {
        $this->html .= $html;
    }
    public function output () {
        $this->html = $this->header() . $this->html . $this->footer();
       return $this->html;
    }
}

$page = new PageHandler();
$page->input('some content');
echo $page->output();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a class as a document constructor is not out of the ordinary, but I would suggest making a few revisions to your class to be a bit more intentional in your approach. Take a look at the example below for some ideas of how to `class` it up a bit (lolz). Remember - both your `constructor` and your `output buffer` can be great friends when dealing with document output.

```
<?php

class PageHandler
{

    private $html;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->html = $this->getHeader();
    }

    private function getHeader()
    {

        ob_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Nuclear Summer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
        return ob_get_clean();

    }

    private function getFooter()
    {

        ob_start();
?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
        return ob_get_clean();

    }

    function setBody($html)
    {
        $this->html .= $html;
    }

    function getDocument()
    {
        return $this->html . $this->getFooter();
    }

}

?>
```